# AWS Redshift: How to store text field with size greater than 100K

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a text field in parquet file with max length `141598`. I am loading the parquet file to redshift and got the error while loading as the max a `varchar` can store is `65535`.
Is there any other datatype I can use or another alternative to follow?

Error while loading:

`S3 Query Exception (Fetch). Task failed due to an internal error. The length of the data column friends is longer than the length defined in the table. Table: 65535, Data: 141598`

Comment: no, that is the max.

Answer (score 5):

No, the maximum length of a [VARCHAR data type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html) is 65535 bytes and that is the longest data type that Redshift is capable of storing. Note that length is in *bytes*, not characters, so the actual number of characters stored depends on their byte length.

If the data is already in parquet format then possibly you don't need to load this data into a Redshift table at all, instead you could create a Spectrum [external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) over it. The external table definition will only support a VARCHAR definition of 65535, the same as a normal table, and any query against the column will silently truncate additional characters beyond that length - however the original data will be preserved in the parquet file and potentially accessible by other means if needed.